# Lighten an image on hover

Tags: image, colors, hover, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm setting up a portfolio webpage, and I want the images to be coloured with a colour from the logo 50% solid until mouseover, which makes the colour fade out and reveal the image properly.

Here's the site so far; www.cmvisual.com

Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you probably want to put a div with a background color and partial opacity 
over the image, and then use a CSS transition (preferably) or Javascript to animate the transition.

Maybe start at half opacity, then go to 0 opacity on rollover.

What you REALLY want is CSS blend modes, but that isn't fully supported yet.

Comment: Blend modes would be amazing, but I'd be fine with just a simple fade as it is. Given that I want a different colour on each image, would that require a new div per image?